# CSS Breakpoint not working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I designed a responsive web site and it has the following breakpoints. I added a background color to each breakpoint to make sure they work:

```
@media (min-device-width: 1366px) /*1366px or less*/ (background is blue)
@media (min-device-width: 1024px) /*1024px or less*/ (background is pink)
@media (max-width: 991.98px) /*992px or less*/ (background is grey)
@media (max-width: 767.98px /*768px or less*/ (background is green)
@media (max-width: 575.98px)  /*576px or less*/ (background is yellow)
```

All of them work except the "blue" one, and I can't figure out why.
That very first one is my desktop breakpoint and is a file called "custom.css".  All the other breakpoints are in a separate file called "responsive.css"

You can view the site [here](http://www.devcore.tech/simplecash/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `min-width` or `min-device-width:` for media queries, you have to order them the other way round. Look at the beginning of your code:

```
@media (min-device-width: 1366px) /*1366px or MORE!*/ (background is blue)
@media (min-device-width: 1024px) /*1024px or MORE!*/ (background is pink)
```

The second one (`min-device-width: 1024px`) will ALWAYS apply for any device that's wider than 1024px, simply because it will overwrite the first one since it follows after and any device *wider* than 1366 will also be wider than 1024!

(Your "... or less" assumption is wrong: `min-width: ...` means "...or MORE")

So just put them in the opposite order:

```
@media (min-device-width: 1024px) /*1024px or MORE*/ (background is pink)
@media (min-device-width: 1366px) /*1366px or MORE*/ (background is blue)
```

...or use `max-width` instead.

---

Yet another possible solution:

```
@media (min-width: 1025px) /*1025px or MORE*/ (background is blue)
@media (max-width: 1024px) /*1024px or less*/ (background is pink)
@media (max-width: 991.98px) /*992px or less*/ (background is grey)
@media (max-width: 767.98px /*768px or less*/ (background is green)
@media (max-width: 575.98px)  /*576px or less*/ (background is yellow)
```

(The first one covers everything wider than 1024, then you have four breakpoints as you already had it)

Comment: I've tried both your options and in both cases the blue background breakpoint works but the pink background breakpoint dissapears.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: First, I would NOT mix `device-width` and `width` in the same stylesheet for the same element, and second, if you just use `width`, the step between 992px and 1024px is rather small (32px range), so I would change these values to actually see all stages.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Pink color is taking precedence over blue for the background:

[image]

Furthermore, after looking into your CSS source files, I see that the Media constraint for the blue color doesn't actually have a media constraint on it:

[image]

So, what is happening is that the pink color is taking precedence over the blue background color since its CSS file responsive.css is being loaded after custom.css. To fix this, either load custom.css second (may or may not fix), or ideally, make sure you have the correct media constraint in place on the body element within custom.css.